# Find all $x$ in $D_4$ such that $ax(a^{-1}) = b$.

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

Consider the dihedral group $D_4$. Consider also the elements $a= r_1$ and $b= S_1$ of $D_4$.
Find all $x$ in $D_4$ such that $ax(a^{-1}) = b$.
Do both $a$ and ($a^{-1}$) cancel each other out? If not, how do I solve this?

Comment: by $r_1$ ans $S_1$ do you mean the standard generators? and $|D_4| = 8$? please write the expression for $D_4$ that you are using.

Comment: By r1 I mean rot π/2 and s1 is ref 0. |D4| = 8. I'm not sure what you mean by expression for D4 as I'm not given one

Comment: I don't believe that you have stated this correctly. As it stands, there is a unique such $x$, namely $a^{-1}ba$.

Comment: Hint: Consider that if $D_4 = \langle r,s \rangle$, such that, $ r^2 = s^4 = 1$ and $ rsr = s^{-1} = s^{3}$. Then every element in $D_4$ is of the form: $r^{i}s^{j}$, with $0 \leq i < 2$ and $0 \leq j < 4$. This means each exponent belongs to $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ and $\mathbb{Z_{4}}$ respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D_n := \langle r, s : |r| = n, |s| = 1, rs = sr^{-1}, s \neq r^i, \forall i \rangle, n \geq 3$ be the dihedral group of order $2n$ with the standard generators ($r$ is the rotation by $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ and $s$ is reflection through the vertex $1$ and origin). Then every element of $D_n$ can be written uniquely as $r^is^j, 1\leq i \leq n, j = 1, 2.$

In this case $n = 4$ and with this notations $r_1 = r, s_1 = s$ (if I understand correctly). So we need to find all $x \in D_4$ such that $rxr^{-1} = s.$ Now $x$ is of the form $r^is^j.$ First let $j = 0.$ Then $rxr^{-1} = rr^ir^{-1} = r^i.$ So there is no solution in this case. Now let $j = 1.$ Then $rxr^{-1} = rr^isr^{-1} = r^{i+2}s.$ Hence $rxr^{-1} = s \Rightarrow r^{i+2}s = s \Rightarrow r^{i+2} = 1 \Rightarrow i = 2.$ In this case, the only choice for $x$ is $r^2s.$

Obviously, you can do it more directly as follows: $rxr^{-1}=s \Rightarrow x = r^2s.$